# Populate email field is wp-signup.php

Tags: plugin-gravity-forms, wp-signup

I am collecting email on the home page of my website using gravity form, and redirect user to the wp-signup.php page. How can i populate the email field of wp-signup.php with the user entry (email) on gravity form.

Will be great of this can be achieved.